# Fully encrypted Linux Mint install over multiple drives

Tags: partition, encryption, boot-loader, whole-drive-encryption

I want to fully encrypt a fresh install of Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.X, including the boot-loader. I need a fully secure system.

My current setup is as follows, which is pretty much how I'd like the future setup to be:

1. 250GB SSD as main OS drive.

   - sda1 is 550MB /boot
   - sda2 is 50GB / for OS
   - sda3 is 200GB blank formatted space for games.
2. 1TB HDD for Home/data drive at sdb1.
3. 1TB SSD Games drive at sdc1.

The plan is to backup everything, wipe everything completely with the `dd urandom` command, then reinstall Linux Mint and encrypt everything from a fresh install. I'd like 1 password to decrypt all the drives on boot-up, and another password to login.

I've been using Linux about a year now, and computers for like 20 years, so I'm new but not a total noob. I'd still likely need step by step instructions and a brief description. And whatever troubleshooting I might need so I don't get locked out of my own system.

I thought I came across instructions to do exactly what I wanted several months ago, but I've looked since and can't seem to find it. I saw this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption) which is close but doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for. Most of the encryption guides I've seen aren't for full encryption for a multi-drive setup and the boot-loader. Please help.

Comment: Debian provides FDE as part of its standard installation. I'm sure other distros do, too

Comment: During the installation of Linux Mint, you can select full disk encryption for all of the disks.

Comment: I thought the standard installer could auto encrypt the OS and /home, but not other drives, and I didn't think the bootloader was encrypted through the standard installer. If the standard automatic installer can encrypt every drive like I want, then awsome. Is there any guide available? I thought encrypting extra drives and the bootloader could only be done manually, though I'd be glad to be wrong.